# To many lists of Unique Words

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is a homework project from last week. I had problems so did not turn it it. But I like to go back and see if I can make them work. Now that I have it printing the right words in alphabetical order. I have the problem that it is printing 3 separate lists of unique words all with different number of words in the lists. How can I fix this?

```
import string
def process_line(line_str,word_set):
    line_str=line_str.strip()
    list_of_words=line_str.split()
for word in list_of_words:
    if word!="--":
        word=word.strip()
        word=word.strip(string.punctuation)
        word=word.lower()
        word_set.add(word)
def pretty_print(word_set):
    list_of_words=[]
    for w in word_set:
        list_of_words.append(w)
        list_of_words.sort()
    for w in list_of_words:
        print(w,end=" ")
word_set=set([])
fObject=open("gettysburg.txt")
for line_str in fObject:
    process_line(line_str,word_set)
    print("\nlength of the word set: ",len(word_set))
    print("\nUnique words in set: ")
    pretty_print(word_set)
```

Below is the output I get, I only want it to give me the last one with the 138 words. Appreciate any help.

```
length of the word set:  29

Unique words in set:

a ago all and are brought conceived continent created dedicated equal fathers forth four in liberty men nation new on our proposition score seven that the this to years 

length of the word set:  71

Unique words in set:

a ago all altogether and any are as battlefield brought can civil come conceived continent created dedicate dedicated do endure engaged equal fathers field final fitting for forth four gave great have here in is it liberty live lives long men met might nation new now of on or our place portion proper proposition resting score seven should so testing that the their this those to war we whether who years 

length of the word set:  138

Unique words in set:

a above add advanced ago all altogether and any are as battlefield be before birth brave brought but by can cause civil come conceived consecrate consecrated continent created dead dedicate dedicated detract devotion did died do earth endure engaged equal far fathers field final fitting for forget forth fought four freedom from full gave god government great ground hallow have here highly honored in increased is it larger last liberty little live lives living long measure men met might nation never new nobly nor not note now of on or our people perish place poor portion power proper proposition rather remaining remember resolve resting say score sense seven shall should so struggled take task testing that the their these they this those thus to under unfinished us vain war we what whether which who will work world years
```

Answer (score 1):

Take last 3 lines out of for:

```
....
for line_str in fObject:
    process_line(line_str,word_set)

print("\nlength of the word set: ",len(word_set))
print("\nUnique words in set: ")
pretty_print(word_set)
```

Comment: Thank you, It is always the easiest things. I could have sworn i tried that, but after working so long on it, I probably just thought I did.

Comment: Happens sometimes :)